# Hibernate inverse="true" saving parent saves children when cascade="all"

Tags: java, hibernate

When I read about cascade and inverse it is said that both are doing totally separate things.
Cascade: In cascade, after one operation (save, update and delete) is done, it decide whether it need to call other operations (save, update and delete) on another entities which has relationship with each other.
Inverse: This is used to decide which side is the relationship owner to manage the relationship (insert or update of the foreign key column).

Lets say i save parent that has some children. So when i set one-to-many with inverse="true" cascade="all" on one hand I want that child is owner of the relationship, so saving parent should change children collection, however when I 
add cascade="all" hibernate would change this behaviour and persist children.

So how they are different if cascade changes behaviour of inverse?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: so how they are different if cascade changes behaviour of inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example:

- one Order has many Lines: OneToMany association
- Many Lines share one parent Order: ManyToOne association

The owner side is Line. The inverse side is Order.

That means that if you persist an `Order`, persist a `Line`, add the line to the collection `Order.lines`, but don't set `Line.order`, Hibernate will consider that no association exists between those two entities. Why? Because you only set the inverse side of the association (`Order.lines`), and not the owner side (`Line.order`).

Cascade has nothing to do with this. Let's say `Order.lines` is annotated with `cascade=PERSIST`. That means that if you create an `Order`, create a `Line`, add the `Line` to `Order.lines`, and persist the Order, Hibernate will also automatically call `persist()` on the `Line`. The `Line` will thus be persisted without having to explicitely call `persist()` with this line. But the association between the two entities still won't be saved in the database, because you still haven't set the owner side of the association: `Line.order`.

Comment: I see, so they both would be saved but line.order would be null, so load from db would not work I mean there is n o info about relation so it is lost, we would get empty line collection?

Comment: Loading the entities from DB would work fine. But the Line wouldn't have any order, and the order wouldn't have any line.